# Dynamic createElement onclick event stored with event and not in page's javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, iframe, dynamic-content

I have the following code:

```js
function AddiFrameTab(ChildDivID, iFrameLink, ParentJobID, Extension, textDisplay) {
        var span = document.createElement('span');
        span.classList.add('glyphicon');
        span.classList.add('glyphicon-remove');
        span.onclick = function () {
            window.parent.$('#' + ChildDivID).remove();
            window.parent.$('#navTab' + ChildDivID).remove();
            if (window.parent.$('#navTabSearchJobsFromParent' + ParentJobID).length)
                window.parent.$('.nav-tabs a[href="#SearchJobsFromParent"' + ParentJobID + ']').tab('show');
            else if (window.parent.$('#navTabsSearchJobs').length)
                window.parent.$('.nav-tabs a[href="#SearchJobs"]').tab('show');
            else
                window.parent.$('.nav-tabs a[href="#home"]').tab('show');
        }

        var Anchor = document.createElement('a');
        Anchor.href = '#' + ChildDivID;
        Anchor.setAttribute('data-toggle', 'tab');
        Anchor.innerText = textDisplay + '\t';
        Anchor.id = 'navTab' + ChildDivID;
        Anchor.appendChild(span);

        var Tab = document.createElement('li');
        Tab.appendChild(Anchor);

        var TabBar = window.parent.document.getElementById('TabBar');
        TabBar.appendChild(Tab);

        var iFrame = document.createElement('iframe');
        iFrame.id = 'iFrame' + ChildDivID
        iFrame.src = '/' + iFrameLink + '.aspx?JobNumber=' + ParentJobID + '&Extension=' + Extension;
        iFrame.width = "100%";
        iFrame.height = 710;
        iFrame.frameBorder = 0;
        iFrame.setAttribute('webkitAllowFullScreen', '');
        iFrame.setAttribute('mozallowfullscreen', '');
        iFrame.setAttribute('allowFullScreen', '');

        var tabPane = document.createElement('div');
        tabPane.classList.add('tab-pane');
        tabPane.id = ChildDivID;

        tabPane.appendChild(iFrame);

        var TabContainer = window.parent.document.getElementById('TabContainer');
        TabContainer.appendChild(tabPane);
    }
```

My problem is that the code in question is adding a two DOM elements to the iFrame's parent. When this iFrame is removed with the same style of code, the onclick event ceases to function as it's removed from memory.

Bottom line: Is there a better way of performing this same functionality that will possibly store the onclick event with the DOM element, instead of with the JavaScript that will be removed from memory?

Comment: Event handlers are always attached to elements.  Your question makes little sense, but you're probably looking for event delegation.

Comment: I don't quite understand how my question makes little sense.

I want to be able to remove DOM elements after the code that created them is destroyed. I am trying to create a very dynamic website with the use of iFrames to make it modular.

Comment: Code is never "destroyed" (unless you mean losing all references to a function).  I still don't know what you're trying to do.

Comment: I am creating DOM elements form an iFrame, for the iFrames parent. Which is another iFrame. I want to be able to destroy the 2nd created object (jQuery's .remove() function) after the object that created has been destroyed as well (via the same jQuery .remove() function). Unless there's a better way to do it.